# .NET Standard 2.0 / EntityFrameworkCore / DB2 / IBM.EntityFrameworkCore issue

Tags: db2, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-standard-2.0

Does anyone here has experience with [IBM.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.EntityFrameworkCore/) package? I've created a .NET Standard 2.0 library project in VS2017, added mentioned package, and tried to make it work by following [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/DB2DotnetCore?lang=en) and [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Getting_started_with_IBM_EntityFramework_Core_using_Visual_Studio_2015?lang=en) tutorial from IBM website, with no luck. I get the project compiled, but at the runtime I'm getting a `System.TypeLoadException` with the following message:

```
Method 'ApplyServices' in type 'IBM.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.Db2OptionsExtension' from assembly 'IBM.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=1.1.1.101, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208' does not have an implementation.
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

**Update:** The exception happens as soon as I try to use the context. It means **after** the context is successfully created, but **before** `DbContext.OnConfiguring` call happens.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it. It turned out that this exception happens if actual entity types (i.e. `MyType`) aren't defined in the same assembly (project) as the context. In my solution I had entity types defined in one project, and `DbContext`defined in a different project, that references the first one, of course.

The reason for me to have such design was in the fact that there are two different packages (depending on the actual OS): [IBM.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.EntityFrameworkCore/) and [IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-lnx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-lnx/). So I've created two different projects, each referencing one of these packages. Still, I wanted to have all the entity types defined once... But obviously it cannot work like that.

**Update**: Sadly, it turned out that this isn't the only issue. I've ran into another one, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45826715/ibm-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-onconfiguring-and-dbcontext-onmodelcreating). Thumbs down for DB2 .NET team! It's always frustrating to work with...

Comment: Hello, I have just the same problem, did you solve it? in my case I'm migrating to .net 4.6