# IBM.EntityFrameworkCore - DbContext.OnConfiguring and DbContext.OnModelCreating aren't called

Tags: db2, entity-framework-core

As soon as I've solved [one issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782871/net-standard-2-0-entityframeworkcore-db2-ibm-entityframeworkcore-issue) with [IBM.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.EntityFrameworkCore/), another one has arose. Everything is soooo hard and painful with DB2 and their .NET team...

The problem: I have several `EntityFrameworkCore` - based projects in the same VS solution, for example `MyDb2EfModel`, `MyMsSqlEfModel`, and `MyNpgsqlEfModel`. (It's kind of a complex data-integration scenario.) On top of that I have a CLI project which references all the three and performs actual data ops. When the CLI project references only `MyDb2EfModel` project - `IBM.EntityFrameworkCore` works as expected. But as soon as I add references to the remaining two projects - it simply stops working and throws some misleading exception. The exception happens because overridden `DbContext.OnConfiguring` and `DbContext.OnModelCreating` methods aren't called anymore. When there's only one reference (`MyDb2EfModel`) the methods get called as expected, and everything works. But with all three library projects referenced - they aren't called anymore.

Let's also note that the mentioned methods get called on `DbContext` instances from `MyMsSqlEfModel` and `MyNpgsqlEfModel` libraries. The only one that stops working is `MyDb2EfModel` (which is based on `IBM.EntityFrameworkCore`).

**Thumbs down for IBM and their .NET team!** It's ridiculous how these guys are making things be 100 times more complicated then with any other DB.

The question is obvious: Does anyone has any experience in a similar scenario, and hopefully any suggestion how to resolve the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Suggest you open a PMR with IBM's paid support channel to determine whether IBM's offering supports exactly what you want to do. That is , if the IBM documentation for their .NET does not already let you answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @mao! But sadly I don't have access to IBM's paid support.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the reason. It turned out that it's about `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version. Currently available version of `IBM.EntityFrameworkCore` is `1.1.1.101` (.NET Standard 1.6), and it uses `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version `1.1.1` or `1.1.2`. It **cannot** be used with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version `2.0.0` (.NET Standard 2.0) - it throws the exception I was getting.

In the other two libraries I've used `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` version `2.0.0` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` version `2.0.0`, both depending on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version `2.0.0` (all in .NET Standard 2.0).

So when I referenced only `MyDb2EfModel` in my CLI project everything was working because only `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version `1.1.2` is referenced and used. But as soon as I add reference to another projects CLI ends up with dependencies on both `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version `1.1.2` and `2.0.0` versions, and the newer (`2.0.0`) is loaded and used. And `IBM.EntityFrameworkCore` was failing because it cannot use it.

How to solve? Either wait for `IBM.EntityFrameworkCore` for .NET Standard 2.0, or downgrade other references to ensure that `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version `2.0.0` isn't used anywhere (which will cause other headaches).

So although it's not about a bug in `IBM.EntityFrameworkCore`, IBM DB2 .NET team is still to blame for not having .NET Standard 2.0 at least preview published, although .NET Standard 2.0 is available for almost a year now, recently reaching its "release" version. And there are more things to blame IBM DB2 .NET team for (unrelated to this particular issue).

Comment: Boo on IBM and its shameful .Net support! :( Gr.

Comment: Option 2, move to nodejs and be happier.

Comment: Sadly, this is still an issue in 2018.